# Refactoring job definition (a generic function) in Quartz.Net

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, refactoring, quartz.net

I am trying out Quartz.net, I will have many very similar tasks and was hoping I wouldn't have to type out the whole

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .Build();
```

Spiel each time. So I thought I'd try make my jobs all inherit from a base job that forces them to have certain data e.g.

```
abstract public class BaseJob : IJob
{
    public static abstract string Name { get; }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //Calls an abstract method that does the actual work with some wrapping stuff around it
    }
}
```

Now lets say I implement `Job1` and `Job2` classes that inherit from `BaseJob` I could do this:

```
List<IJobDetail> Jobs = new List<IJobDetail>();

Jobs.Add(JobBuilder.Create<Job1>()
                   .WithIdentity(Job1.Name, "group1")
                   .Build());

Jobs.Add(JobBuilder.Create<Job2>()
                   .WithIdentity(Job2.Name, "group1")
                   .Build());
```

But I would like to refactor that so I can just create a `List<BaseJob> JobList` which I populate somewhere and then fill `Jobs` in a `foreach` loop. Is this possible since `JobBuilder.Create<>()` is a generic method? How can I specify the type if that's the right terminology (i.e. the bit in the `<>`) using a variable?

I tried using `typeof` to no avail e.g. (note this is just on one element but would be basically the same if iterating through)

```
Jobs.Add(JobBuilder.Create<typeof(JobList[0])>()
                   .WithIdentity(JobList[0].Name, "group1")
                   .Build()))
```

And I even tried making `JobList` a `List<Type>` and then

```
Jobs.Add(JobBuilder.Create<JobList[0]>()
                   .WithIdentity(JobList[0].Name, "group1")
                   .Build()))
```

but this is also no good. Is there a way to do this? Can Reflection help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a version of JobBuilder.Create that takes the type as a parameter and is not generic. So you can call:

```
foreach (var jobType in jobTypeList)
{
    JobBuilder.Create(jobType).WithIdentity()...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically, your question has less to do with quartz.net, and more to do with parametric generic invocations. This post can help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22615/Dynamically-Invoke-Generic-Methods

Comment: Thanks, luckily the other solutions have mitigated the need for this but this is essentially what I thought I would have to know but did not really know how

Answer (score 1):

I would create a base job with extended properties:

- Name
- Group
- Type

Sample here:

```
public class BaseJob : IJob
{
    public virtual void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobKey jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;

        string message = string.Format("Job Key:{0} - Trigger Key:{1} - Start Time:{2} - Schedule Fire Time: {3}", context.JobDetail.Key, context.Trigger.Key, context.Trigger.StartTimeUtc, context.ScheduledFireTimeUtc);

        ILog log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        log.Debug(message);

        Console.WriteLine(new String('*', 100));

        Console.WriteLine("Trigger Info: " + message);
        Console.WriteLine("Next Schedule: " + context.Trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc());

        Console.WriteLine(new String('*', 100));
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the inherited job:

```
public class InheritedJob1 : BaseJob
{
}
```

Now you can define your list of jobs:

```
IList<BaseJob> jobs = new List<BaseJob>();
jobs.Add(new BaseJob() { Name = "Job1", Group = "MYGROUP", Type = typeof(InheritedJob1) });
jobs.Add(new BaseJob() { Name = "Job2", Group = "MYGROUP", Type = typeof(InheritedJob2) });
jobs.Add(new BaseJob() { Name = "Job3", Group = "MYGROUP", Type = typeof(InheritedJob3) });
```

specifying eache type.

So you can schedule all your listed jobs easily:

```
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    IJobDetail quartzJob = JobBuilder.Create(job.Type)
        .WithIdentity(job.Name, job.Group)
        .Build();

    ITrigger quartzTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trg_" + job.Name, job.Group)
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(30).RepeatForever())
            .Build();

    Scheduler.ScheduleJob(quartzJob, quartzTrigger);
}
```

You can download a working sample [here](https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzNetInheritance).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll stick with a static Name field etc as the inherited tasks only really should have one instance. But I'll look into setting the inherited type like that... The crux of the matter though was that `JobBuilder` had a non-generic `Create()` method